# Chrome on macOS doesn't select visible tab after switching windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I use a multi-window setup on a MacBook, which requires me to swipe on the trackpad to change windows.

If I have full-screen Chrome open in window A then swipe to view another full-screen Chrome in window B, Chrome in window A remains selected. This is annoying because if I swipe to window A and close a tab, the last used tab in window B will close instead.

Is there a suggested fix for this?